# Finding Factorials and Ending zeros of a Factorial Number

Tags: c

**I have a problem. I want to find factorial of big numbers.**

Ex: 1555! = ?.
195! = ?.

My main problem is that I want to know the exact number of ending 0's of the factorial numbers.

I use the following formula:
  (m!)^n = m! = 2*10^(n-1) + 2^2 * 10^(n-2) + ------- + 2^n.

with this I can solve the other factorials for number of ending 0's like this.

100!= 2*10^1 + 2^2*10^0 = 20+4 = 24

100! has 24 ending 0's as per this calculation.

But, then I got other problem,

Ex: For 95!

i) 95! = (100 - 5)! = 24 - 2*5^(1-1) = 24 - 2 = 22 => 95! has 22 0's.

ii) 95! = (90 + 5)! = 9*(2*10^0) + 2*5^0)= 18+2 = 20 => 95! has 20 0's.

this is my problem. By using the above formula I got two different answers and I am confused, I don't get the perfect answer so please help me to find it.

***Thank you...***

Comment: You are insane. 100! does not equals 95! + 5!. Neither it is equal to 100!- 5! Read Maths First

Comment: Try this [link](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=84130)

Comment: Yes sir, I know that. But this is used for finding the ending zeros for factorial as per the formula I got from google. :)

Comment: this should probably be on mathmatics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

The number of trailing zeros in n! is the number of factors of 5 in the sequence 1, 2, ..., n. This is because a trailing zeros is the number of factors of 10 in the result, and 10 has a prime factorisation of 5 x 2. There's always more factors of 2 than 5, so the number of 5's gives the result.

The number of factors of 5 is... `[n/5] + [n/25] + ... + [n/(5^k)] + ...` where `[ ]` means round down (*floor*).

What should the code look like to compute this? Something like this perhaps.

```
int trailing_factorial_zeros(int n) {
    int result = 0;
    int m5 = 5;
    while (n >= m5) {
        result += n / m5;
        m5 *= 5;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad question, probably belongs on Math site anyway.  But here's a thought for you:

First 100! = 100 * 99!

99! = 99 * 98! and so forth until
1! = 1, and 0! = 1.

You want to know how many trailing 0's are in N! (at least that is how I understand the question).

Think of how many are in 10!

```
10! = 3628800
```

so there are two.  The reason why is because only 2*5 = a number with a trailing 0 along with 10.  So we have a total of 2.  (5*4 has a trailing 0 but 4 is a multiple of 2, and besides, we only get to multiply individual numbers once)

It is a good bet, then, that 20! has 4 (it does).

It's now your job to prove (or disprove) that this pattern will hold, and then come up with a way to code it.

Comment: good answer for bad question...

Comment: Sir, Yes My Que is wrong. But I have a Que.  How many ending zeros. in the factorial of  125! please help me for finding formula for the ending zeros from high numbers like this